# Is play time shared across PS3 and PC?

Tags: ps3, steam, portal-2, steam-cloud

If I am playing Portal 2 on a PS3 activated with my Steam account, does play time get added to my stats in the same way as trophies/achievements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, according to steam support: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5477-WPJM-9388#existingsteamacc